# Angular 2 root's route is always active

Tags: javascript, angular

Recently I read [this useful article about Angular 2 Router](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-routing#.V1f-wZVefIo.facebook) and looked at [the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1EORL6bVsTEXLqHwTcpt?p=preview). Everything seemed to be perfect. But when I tried to determine the active route based on `router-link-active` class, I found out that the root route always active.

Here is the piece of codes of the app.component.ts where the 'main' routes are configured:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    <div class="outer-outlet">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  // add our router directives we will be using
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    // these are our two routes
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent }, // , useAsDefault: true}, // coming soon
    { path: '/about', name: 'About', component: AboutComponent }
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

If I change the path from `'/'` to `'/home'` and `<a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>` to `<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>` the default component (which has to be HomeComponent) disappears. The HomeComponent will be activated only if the link is clicked and the `router-link-active` will be added and removed correctly everytime we change to another route.

Is this a bug or there is something wrong with the routes' configuration?

Comment: This link could be interesting for you https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8397

Comment: Hi @yurzui , thanks for the link. It's very helpful. Turns out that's the way Angular 2 route works. So I have to do my own workaround.. :(

Comment: yurzui s link seems to be about the new router. For the beta and RC.1 `@angular/router-deprecated` https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5334 seems to be the related issue.

Comment: I'm using the new router for the demo. So I think the link is related.

Comment: @asubanovsky please share your workaround if you have it, I am experiencing the same face palming with the 'Home' being always active

Comment: @asubanovsky, I assume you have to use a proxy server like `nginx` anyway to make your pages refreshable. With the server you can rewrite the long urls like `/option/home` back to the `/home`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Adding the following property to your home anchor worked for me.
`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"`

find out more https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8397#issuecomment-237314970

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, for other looking for this, here is the official documentation on this feature: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Answer (score 3):

This is how it will work:

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bug to my knowledge, you need to have a fallback component for `/` or unknown paths. (most likely HomeComponent)

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: '*', name: component: HomeComponent }
]);
```

This though is using the new `Router` module (not the deprecated one) and works in `rc.0` and `rc.1`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it doesn't help. I think, when we define a root route "/", it makes another route such as "/about" behave as its children. So that the "route-link-active" class appears.