# Angular 2 routerLinkActive always active for base path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this code for my navbar:

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="['nav-active']">HOME</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/about']" [routerLinkActive]="['nav-active']">ABOUT</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/records']" [routerLinkActive]="['nav-active']">RECORDS</a>
</nav>
```

The problem is the HOME nav point always gets the class because / seems to be always active.
Is this avoidable with a small and simple solution?

Thanks for the help

Edit:

this is the solution for now:

[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue.
A few workarounds are detailed in this thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8397

From Github Thread:

"you need to add an additional option to your routerLink."

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
```

Then your home route will only be active if you're on the exact route. The home route with an empty path will be a partial match on all routes

Answer (score 102):

As suggested by [@TomRaine in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097185/3763649), you can add the property `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` to your element:

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/']" 
      [routerLinkActive]="['nav-active']"
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    HOME
  </a>
  ...
</nav>
```

Comment: If I go to about page from home page and refresh the page, I still see home page active. Any idea how to fixed this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<button routerLink="/" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }" routerLinkActive="nav-button-active"
                mat-button mat-raised-button
                class="w-100 mb-3 nav-buttons">
          Dashboard
</button>
```

Just make rure to add the property,
`[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"`.